# export compliance for submitting to ios app store as an individual developer

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am using basic ssl for my app that i am planning to submit at the iOS app store. From all the research it seems that i need to get an ERN from BIS for export compliance.

While registering the same i see company name / CIN being asked as a part of the process. I am uploading the app from a country outside US. So I am totally confused now - do i need to register my company in my country first and then apply for a CIN inorder to go ahead with ERN registration procedure? Or Can i obtain ERN as an individual? Thanks for any help.

I see this at [Simplified Network Application Process](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/licensing/simplified-network-application-process-redesign-snap-r/cin-request)

> SNAP-R Access
>
> SNAP-R allows users to submit export license applications, commodity
>   classification requests, encryption registration, reexport license
>   applications, and license exception AGR notifications via the
>   Internet. You must have a Company Identification Number (CIN) and an
>   active user account to access SNAP-R.

P.S. I am not sure if this is the right forum for this question. If not any guidance to alternate forum will be much appreciated. Thanks again!